# DFT in Complex numbers with 5 digit precision

Tags: c++, precision, complex-numbers, polynomial-math, polynomials

This is a question I am trying to solve in C++;

Given a polynomial **A(x)** that is specified with degree **d-1** and its coefficients are a0, a1, a2, a3 ...ad-1. Let **a** be d dimensional vector of these coefficients. Given an integer n output vector DFT(a,n) where DFT(a,n) is defined as [see here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1tGm7j8cDbSObwWqpuR9gMyKpWXWz9hQp).

[INPUT and OUTPUT format](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1YBzzNnqFDatfaPdVc5Cz1vef6Wr_WSFY)

My code here is

```
    #include<bits/stdc++.h>
    #include<complex>
    #include <iomanip>
    using namespace std;

    void DfT(vector<double> &a, vector<double> &b, int n, int d){
        vector<double> ans1, ans2;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            double k=(M_PI*2.00000)/n;
            k=round(k*1e5)/1e5;
            //cout<<k<<" ";
            double r=cos(i*k), im=sin(i*k);
            r=round(r*1e5)/1e5;
            im=round(im*1e5)/1e5;
            double wr=1,wi=0;
        for(int j=0;j<d;j++){
            double a1=wr*a[j]-wi*b[j];
            a1=round(a1*1e5)/1e5;
            double b1=wr*b[j]+wi*a[j];
            b1=round(b1*1e5)/1e5;
            ans1.push_back(a1);
            ans2.push_back(b1);
            double temp=wr;
            wr=wr*r-wi*im;
            wr=round(wr*1e5)/1e5;
            wi=temp*im+r*wi;
            wi=round(wi*1e5)/1e5;
        }

    }
        for(auto &it:ans1)cout<<fixed<<setprecision(5)<<it<<" "<<endl;
        for(auto &it:ans2)cout<<fixed<<setprecision(5)<<it<<" ";

    }
    int main(){
        int d,n;      //d -1 is the degree of the polynomial A(x)
        cin>>d;
        vector<double> a,b;
        for(int i=0;i<d;i++){
            double t;
            cin>>t;
            a.push_back(t);   // the real part of polynomial
        }
        for(int i=0;i<d;i++){
            double t;
            cin>>t;
            b.push_back(t);           // imaginary part of polynomial
        }
        cin>>n;               // n is surely power of 2 and we find 
        //nth root of infinity and put the value of roots in polynomial A(x) as x.
        FfT(a,b,n,d);    //we have to output the value of polynomial ie A(w1),A(w2).. with precision to 5 decimal places 
        return 0;
    }
```

logic seems to be fine but it also looks like there is loss in precision for answer. Only few of test cases are being passed.
Kindly help

Comment: It looks like you should use full precision for the calculation but print the result with 5 digits.

Comment: I replaced 1e5 with 1e7 everywhere but when i print it with precision 5, there is still same error. In some test cases there is even TLE

Comment: Remove all rounding from calculations and let the output stream’s precision handle the rounding.

Comment: Okay did that too... I guess now it has to do with logic now ... because precision part cannot be improved beyond what you suggested and there is still TLE for some cases

Comment: The `bits/stdc++` header is not standard and should never be included. You will need `vector`, `cmath`, `iostream` and maybe others.

Comment: Your calculations of `wr` and `wi` should be more on-the-spot instead of iterative. Any addition or subtraction of floating point values first converts the value with smaller absolute value to the same exponent as the other, losing precision. What’s 1e6 plus 1? First adjust the exponent of 1 so it becomes 0.000001e6 then you can add them. What about 1e50 plus 1 or plus 1e-50? There’s only 51 bits of precision in a `double`.